# Embed a file into an external exe with C#

Tags: c#, file, embed, executable, interpreter

So I've made an interpreted programming language, and everything is going fine except one thing: I want to make a "compiler" that will embed the user's code into a copy of the interpreter, that way all the user needs to do is double click the executable with the code embedded into it and it would run.

So the question is: how can I embed a file into an already compiled executable? I do have access to the executable *before* it's compiled, but the embedding process must happen after.

I would prefer the solution to be in C# but I'm desperate and could use C++ or VB.NET, or even a batch file

Comment: Which type of file would you like to embed?

Comment: @FeliceM Just a text file containing the code that will be interpreted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some intense googling I found a library called `Mono.Cecil` which does exactly what I want. I was able to inject a file into an executable file by using the following code:

```
string fileName = "Interpreter.exe"; // The file which will have toInject injected in it
string outputName = "Compiled.exe";  // The output file to compile
string toInject = "program.txt";     // The file we will be injecting into fileName
string resourceName = "program.txt"; // The name of the file once it's inside fileName

var module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(filename);

var file = new EmbeddedResource(
    resourceName,
    ManifestResourceAttributes.Private,
    File.ReadAllBytes(toInject));

module.Resources.Add(file);

module.Write(outputName);
```